# Flexbox won't wrap within table in IE 10 and 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, responsive-design, flexbox

I'm using Flexbox inside a table, and it's not working in IE 10 and 11.  Before you tell me to stop using the table, let me explain that the table is in a vendor's code, and I've been asked to work within the HTML structures which lie outside my control.  But I really want to use flexbox, so that wrapping can occur at any screen width.

I've created a small example of this at:   https://jsfiddle.net/6fv3Lekd/18/

My goals are as follows:

- I need the blue boxes to wrap just like the purple ones do, when resizing the browser.  (Works great in Chrome and other browsers.)
- I need to
  use a fixed-pixel flex-basis, like the 100px in this example, not a
  percentage.
- I want this to work inside a `<td>` table cell, where the
  table, tbody, tr and td do not have any fixed width setting.

(NOTE:  I'm well aware that on IE 10 I will need various prefixed CSS attributes such as "-ms-flex-wrap: wrap" instead of the generic modern ones I am using.  But on IE 11, in Developer Tools it's telling me that the ones in my jsfiddle are being accepted (not crossed out), so I'm using this simplified version of my code to demonstrate the issue on IE 11.)

Here is the code found at the jsfiddle link:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="flex-cont">
        <div class="flex-myitem">abc</div>
        <div class="flex-myitem">abc</div>
        <div class="flex-myitem">abc</div>
        <div class="flex-myitem">abc</div>
        <div class="flex-myitem">abc</div>
        <div class="flex-myitem">abc</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="flex-cont">
    <div class="flex-myitem-purple">abc</div>
    <div class="flex-myitem-purple">abc</div>
    <div class="flex-myitem-purple">abc</div>
    <div class="flex-myitem-purple">abc</div>
    <div class="flex-myitem-purple">abc</div>
    <div class="flex-myitem-purple">abc</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.flex-cont {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-myitem {
   flex: 0 0 100px;
   border:1px solid blue;
}
.flex-myitem-purple {
   flex: 0 0 100px;
   border:1px solid purple;
}
```

Just for kicks, I also tried setting the outer `table, tbody, tr and td` to use `display: block`.  This makes them the same as `<div>s` from what I understand, and it started working.  But I can't really do that to my table's tags in this situation.  Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: table is suppose to expand/shrink according to its content, width size can be fixed if set and table-layout set to fixed. I would say, IE gets it right cause nothing tells td to not grow over 100px so flexbox has to wrap content -|-  example : width + table-layout https://jsfiddle.net/6fv3Lekd/21/ (where flexbox comes useless since we have blocks stacked )

Answer (score 5):

As a `table` element is not a block element, it only expand to its content size, and as the `flex` items are allowed to wrap, they do.

To make them behave the same in a table, you need to give the table the same width as the body.

To make IE10 behave, you need to add prefixed (`-ms-`) flex properties.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;         /*  for IE  */
}
.flex-cont {
   display: -ms-flex;
   display: flex;
   -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-myitem {
   -ms-flex: 0 0 100px;
   flex: 0 0 100px;
   border:1px solid blue;
}
.flex-myitem-purple {
   -ms-flex: 0 0 100px;
   flex: 0 0 100px;
   border:1px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="flex-cont">
        <div class="flex-myitem">abc</div>
        <div class="flex-myitem">abc</div>
        <div class="flex-myitem">abc</div>
        <div class="flex-myitem">abc</div>
        <div class="flex-myitem">abc</div>
        <div class="flex-myitem">abc</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="flex-cont">
    <div class="flex-myitem-purple">abc</div>
    <div class="flex-myitem-purple">abc</div>
    <div class="flex-myitem-purple">abc</div>
    <div class="flex-myitem-purple">abc</div>
    <div class="flex-myitem-purple">abc</div>
    <div class="flex-myitem-purple">abc</div>
</div>
```

---

*Updated based on a comment*

The fix using `table-layout: fixed;` for IE can be read more about here: 
[flexbox-not-working-inside-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258836/flexbox-not-working-inside-table/30283067#30283067)

Comment: The blue does *not* wrap in IE11. I haven't tried IE10.

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch Correct...one of these _IE-flex-issues_, add `table-layout: fixed;` to the table rule

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch Updated my answer as well, and with a link that explains the issue

Comment: This worked for me man: `width: 100%;table-layout: fixed;` Saved my hours of time.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working using floats instead of flexbox.  The wrapping behavior for the floats works great on IE 10 and 11, and acts the same as the flexbox wrapping but without browser issues.  (It's not my preference because I want the unique capabilities of flexbox for other reasons in the future, but for this simple example it does the job, and I may end up settling for this approach.)  Example below and posted on a different JSFiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/skurhu46/2/

```
<table class="my-table">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding:0">
      <table class="my-table">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="tbl-item">abc</td>          
          <td class="tbl-item">abc</td>          
          <td class="tbl-item">abc</td>          
          <td class="tbl-item">abc</td>          
          <td class="tbl-item">abc</td>          
          <td class="tbl-item">abc</td>          
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="flex-cont">
    <div class="flex-myitem-purple">abc</div>
    <div class="flex-myitem-purple">abc</div>
    <div class="flex-myitem-purple">abc</div>
    <div class="flex-myitem-purple">abc</div>
    <div class="flex-myitem-purple">abc</div>
    <div class="flex-myitem-purple">abc</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.flex-cont {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-myitem-purple {
   flex: 0 0 100px;
   border:1px solid purple;
}
.tbl-item {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  border:1px solid blue;  
  padding: 0;
}
.my-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```