# HTML Bug? Certain elements are affecting the heights of distant ancestors even with fixed height parents

Tags: html, css

**Why** are these elements affecting the height of a distant ancestor even though its direct parent has a fixed height?

Here there is a simple table with two rows and two columns:

```
<table>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>text</td>
    <td class="column">
      <div id="problem1"></div>
      <div class="text">foo</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>text</td>
    <td class="column">
      <div id="problem2">
        <img>
      </div>
      <div class="text">foo</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

With this stylesheet:

```
.row {
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 55px;

  background-color: #888;
}

#problem1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 10px;
}

#problem2 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 20px;
}

#problem2 img {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

What I would expect is the heights of the rows to follow the height of tallest column. In this case `.column` has a fixed height of `55px` in the CSS.

Instead, the children of the `.column` is influencing the height of the row.

In the first example, a direct child of `.column` sets the height of its `.row`

[The first row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5n6u.png)

Here, the red element is a child of the column (light gray), which is a column and has a fixed height of 55px of the row (dark gray)

However, in the second row, a nested child (in this case an `img`) is the one that determines the final height of the `.row`. Curiously, when I changed the `img` to different type of element (`div`) it did not affect the height of the `.row`.

[The second row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grodk.png)

Here, HTML hierarchy is row > column > blue > green

Furthermore, setting a height for `.row` that is smaller than the largest descendant influencing the height will not work. Even with `!important` for the height property. Like as if the descendant's height takes precedence over the height for the `.row`.

Up until I encountered a situation like this, I believed that HTML elements could only affect the dimensions of their direct parent, not an ancestor more than 1 level up (unless the dimension/property propagates through its parent and the ancestor does not have a fixed height/width)

Quite a bizarre outcome. I would appreciate it if someone could explain what is going on or point me to the right resources to understand this situation.

Thank you for your time.

Here is a fiddle illustrating the post: https://jsfiddle.net/u2745hjy/1/

Comment: I am not smart enough to answer your whole question, but I think part of your problem is that the `.column` inside your td is flex. Flex doesn't work so well inside tables, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258836/flexbox-not-working-inside-table#30283067) might help.

Comment: Why are you adding 55px height to column?

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma I don't think you understand what I'm trying to ask. My question is, if the columns have a set height (55px in this example) and *its* children are bigger, why are *those* elements affecting the height of the row when it should be the columns?

Comment: the answer is because you are scrambling flex and table and this issue is due to table algorithm to calculate the heights of cell/rows

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent `child` element with more height than `parent`. instead you can use `height: 100%` to `child` so that it will take height as their `parent` has.
or you can set `overflow: auto` to `parent` so that it will have `scroll` if their `child` has a higher height than that

Comment: I'm not trying to prevent the child element from being taller than its parent. I'm wondering why an indirect descendant (more than one level deeper) is determining the height of an element even though that descendant has a direct parent with a fixed height.

Comment: its a behavior you can say @Nekomune

Answer (score 0):

Remove 55px height that you have applied to the column.

```
  .column {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      width: 500px;
      background-color: #888;
    }
```

Comment: That is not the problem. I am trying to understand why indirect descendants has a part in determining an element's height, when all its direct children already have different, smaller fixed heights.

Comment: display: flex; is removing table's default style     display: table-cell; due to which table is not behaving any more as a default HTML table element. Avoid using flex with table !